# How can I convert a date in Epoch to "Y-m-d H:i:s" in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, date, transformation, epoch, date-conversion

How can I convert following date in epoch:

> 1293683278

to following readable date:

> 2010-06-23 09:57:58

using Javascript?

Thanks!

Answer (score 46, accepted):

```js
var timestamp = 1293683278;
var date = new Date(timestamp * 1000);

var year = date.getFullYear();
var month = date.getMonth() + 1;
var day = date.getDate();
var hours = date.getHours();
var minutes = date.getMinutes();
var seconds = date.getSeconds();

console.log(year + "-" + month + "-" + day + " " + hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds);
```

See js Date docs for further details

Another way:

```js
var timestamp = 1293683278;
var date = new Date(timestamp * 1000);
var iso = date.toISOString().match(/(\d{4}\-\d{2}\-\d{2})T(\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2})/)

console.log(iso[1] + ' ' + iso[2]);
```

Comment: Thanks! weirdly, when I remove the "*1000" it works, but otherwise it gives me some random numbers..?

Comment: Date in javascript works with microseconds. Are you sure that your timestamps have exactly 10 digits?

Comment: How do i get format like 20130327 using ISOstring match for the date 2013-03-27?

Comment: try `iso[1].replace(/-/g, '') + ' ' + iso[2]`

Comment: just surfed by after some googling, javascript works with milliseconds that is :)

Comment: Your first sample, don't have extra zero, (7 instead 07 as wanted format in question). and second sample converted to ISO format, While not mentioned in the question. It's best answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50768368/1407491

Answer (score 24):

You can use [moment.js](http://momentjs.com) for this.

```
moment.unix(1293683278).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss');
```

Comment: Note from the authors of moment.js: "_we would like to discourage Moment from being used in new projects going forward_" ([source](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/-project-status/)).

Answer (score 3):

Code:

```js
var timestamp = 1293683278;
var d = new Date(timestamp * 1000);

console.log(
  d.getFullYear() + "-" +
  ("00" + (d.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2) + "-" +
  ("00" + d.getDate()).slice(-2) + " " +
  ("00" + d.getHours()).slice(-2) + ":" +
  ("00" + d.getMinutes()).slice(-2) + ":" +
  ("00" + d.getSeconds()).slice(-2)
);
```

Format: `YYYY-MM-DD HH:II:SS`

Result: `2010-12-30 07:57:58`

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/NabiKAZ/9ycovfxt/

Note: For current time, just use: `var d = new Date();` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Before decide using Moment.js in your project, please consider using any other alternatives.

As mentioned at [Moment.js Project Status](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/-project-status).

> **We now generally consider Moment to be a legacy project in maintenance mode. It is not dead, but it is indeed done**

At this point, I'm recommend using [***date-fns library***](https://date-fns.org/). It's lightweight, simple, and support internationalization.

What I really like about *date-fns* is that you just only declare module that you need to use.
Here's my sample code:

```
// Docs: https://date-fns.org/v2.23.0/docs/format
import format from 'date-fns/format'
import id from 'date-fns/locale/id'

function formatTimeLocale(time) {
  return format(
    new Date(time),
    `EEEE, d MMM yyyy 'pukul' HH:mm`,
    {
      locale: id,
    }
  )
}

// This will return: Rabu, 15 Sep 2021 pukul 16:21
const dateTime = formatTimeLocale(1631697689 * 1000)
console.log(dateTime)
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend these short answers for global [UTC](https://time.is/id/UTC) Date-Time:

```js
let timestamp = 1293683278, formattedDate;

// First way
formattedDate = new Date(timestamp * 1000).toJSON().split('.')[0].split('T').join(' ');
console.log(formattedDate);

// Second way
formattedDate = new Date(timestamp * 1000).toJSON().replace('T', ' ').slice(0, -5);
console.log(formattedDate);
```

Comment: and where is a timestamp?

Comment: you can use `Date.now()`

Comment: It gives wrong value for hour.

Comment: The hour value is from UTC. I use this snippet for my postman scripts; works simply awesome :)

Answer (score -1):

```js
/* Get timestamp */
var timestamp = 1293683278;
document.querySelector("#timestamp").innerHTML = "Timestamp: " + timestamp;

/* Get milisecond from timestamp */
var milisecond = 1293683278 * 1000;    
document.querySelector("#milisecond").innerHTML = "Milisecond: " + milisecond;
  
/* Separate milisecond */
var datetime = new Date(milisecond);

var year    = datetime.getFullYear();
var month   = datetime.getMonth() + 1; // (0-11)
var date    = datetime.getDate();
var hour    = datetime.getHours();
var minute  = datetime.getMinutes();
var second  = datetime.getSeconds();

document.querySelector("#datetime").innerHTML = "Datetime: " + 
  year + "-" + addZero(month) + "-" + addZero(date) + " " + 
  addZero(hour) + ":" + addZero(minute) + ":" + addZero(second);      

// Add 0 if argument < 10
function addZero(i) {
  if (i < 10) {
    i = "0" + i
  };  
  return i;
}
```

```html
<p id="timestamp"><p>
<p id="milisecond"><p>
<p id="datetime"><p>
```